# search field with xss vulnerability

Tags: php, xss

I have a XSS vulnerability in my search field, when I put the tipical alert(’xss’) the window appears. I have used vega and OWASP ZAP in order to know where is my fault and I have detected, it is in the underlined code but I dont know how to sanitize, could you help me? Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once("../include/pictures.php");
require_once("../include/comments.php");
require_once("../include/cart.php");
require_once("../include/html_functions.php");
require_once("../include/functions.php");

session_start();

if (!isset($_GET['query']))
{
   http_redirect("/error.php?msg=Error, need to provide a query to search");
}

$pictures = Pictures::get_all_pictures_by_tag($_GET['query']);

?>

<?php our_header("", $_GET['query']); ?>

<div class="column prepend-1 span-24 first last">
<h2>Pictures that are tagged as '<?= $_GET['query']  ?>'</h2>

   <?php thumbnail_pic_list($pictures); ?>

</div>


<?php our_footer(); ?>
```

I cant underlined, the code which is necessary sanitize is:

```
'<?= $_GET['query']  ?>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
htmlspecialchars($_GET['query'])
```